# BeanInstantiationException and other exceptions thrown when initially opening localhost website tab

Tags: java, spring-boot, dependency-injection, vaadin, illegalstateexception

I am fairly new to Vaadin and spring boot in general so recently, when I got this issue, I found myself racking my brain for hours on end not having a clue to what to do. I've done many searches on google and on this forum but I'm fairly confused by many of the recommendations.

**My Issue:**

So my website is a very basic weather application that gets information from free APIs. My application is only one page and its root class "MainLayout.java" class is a Vertical layout that adds all the children layouts/views to itself. My issue is that the constructor for this class seems to be giving an error after I do the following.

1. Startup Spring-boot server (It initializes fine, no errors)
2. Open up a tab of the website and go on localhost:8080
3. **Error occurs and a stack trace is shown with the main errors on top**

*NOTE:* Sometimes when I restart the server again and open the localhost:8080 tab again, it will just work with no errors.

**Short Error Given:**

> There was an exception while trying to navigate to '' with the
> exception message 'Error creating bean with name
> 'com.urweather.app.ui.layouts.MainLayout': Bean instantiation via
> constructor failed; nested exception is
> org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to
> instantiate [com.urweather.app.ui.layouts.MainLayout]: Constructor
> threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException:
> Cannot access state in VaadinSession or UI without locking the
> session.'

**MainLayout class that has the constructor:**

```
package com.urweather.app.ui.layouts;

import com.urweather.app.ui.views.NavigationView;
import com.vaadin.flow.component.dependency.CssImport;
import com.vaadin.flow.component.orderedlayout.VerticalLayout;
import com.vaadin.flow.router.PageTitle;
import com.vaadin.flow.router.PreserveOnRefresh;
import com.vaadin.flow.router.Route;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;

@Route("")
@PageTitle("Ur Weather App")
@CssImport("./styles/shared-styles.css")
@PreserveOnRefresh
public class MainLayout extends VerticalLayout {

    private NavigationView searchBar;
    private CurrentInfoLayout currentInfoLayout;
    private MoreDetailInfoLayout moreDetailInfoLayout;

    @Autowired
    public MainLayout(NavigationView searchBar,
                        CurrentInfoLayout currentInfoLayout,
                        MoreDetailInfoLayout moreDetailInfoLayout) {
        this.searchBar = searchBar;
        this.currentInfoLayout = currentInfoLayout;
        this.moreDetailInfoLayout = moreDetailInfoLayout;
        addClassName("main-layout");

        add(this.searchBar, this.currentInfoLayout, this.moreDetailInfoLayout);
    }
}
```

*Note: The different Views/Layout classes all use @Component and their constructors use dependency injection to inject backend services, etc.*

ANY help would be greatly appreciated! If I need to provide any more information regarding this issue then I will gladly do so. If you have even the smallest hint as to what I should be looking for then I will greatly appreciate that.

Comment: The full stacktrace of that `BeanInstantiationException` would be useful to understand exactly what is going on.

Comment: Thanks, I actually ended up figuring it out after a couple more hours of researching. I found out that I needed to add @ UIScope to every class that used @ Component. This is really weird since the vaadin examples do not need to use the @ UIScope. 
Since I'm new I'm thinking that I may have gotten the dependency-injection wrong or something along those lines.

Comment: The difference there is the use of `@Component` which makes Spring use the class as a global singleton bean unless something else is defined. If you leave out the  `@Component` annotation, Vaadin will instead manage the life cycle similarly to a bean with prototype scope.